# Is a single if statement bad for checking whether a key exists in a map or not for C++

Tags: c++

```
int n, pNumber;
string name, sName;
cin >> n;
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
map<string, int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> name >> pNumber;
    m[name] = pNumber;
}
while (cin >> sName) {
    if (m[sName]) {
        cout << sName << "=" << m[sName] << endl;
    }
    else  {
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    }
}
```

I've went through numerous posts and haven't seen anyone mention just a single if statement with only the map key. I'm not sure whether this code is bad in practice or not. Any clarification would be very helpful.

Comment: If you want to check if the key exists, use the `find` member functions, not `operator[]`.

Comment: This will cause the map to expand when you try to look up a nonexistent key.

Comment: In addition to `find`, the `at` method will throw an exception if the key can't be found. If you're already waiting for the meatbag to hit keys, the extra costs of exception handling probably won't be noticeable.

Comment: Side note: Reading some good documentation can eliminate the need to ask many questions. [Here's what the gold standard C++ document site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) says in the first line of explanatory text: for operator `[]`: *Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.*

Comment: cplusplus.com, usually less accurate but much easier to read by newcomers to C++, spends [a bit more time](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/) on the topic: *If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element is constructed using its default constructor).*

Comment: Also invaluable is stepping through code with a debugger and observing its behaviour, you will have to learn that skill sooner or later. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but that call to `cin.ignore()` doesn’t accomplish anything. All the input is done through stream extractors (`operator>>`), and all stream extractors skip leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't check whether or not the key exists. It tests if the value corresponding to the key is non-zero, creating it if it doesn't exist.

So, yes, it's bad for checking whether a key exists in a map or not because:

1. It will return that the key doesn't exist if the corresponding value is zero.
2. It will create the key if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What would the value of the key be after it has been created?

Comment: The value of the key isn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't check if the value is in map. See [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). Even if it did what you wanted, it would still be less than ideal, because you are doing 2 searchers; 1 to check if the element is in the map and 1 to access that element. The standard way of doing this is using the [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) method, which returns an iterator to the element if it exists, and an end-iterator if it doesn't:

```
if (auto const it = m.find(sName); it != m.end()) {
    std::cout << sName << " : " << it->second << '\n';
} else {
    std::cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

Comment: Now I understand that it's not ideal since it expands the map but after the bracket operator creates the key value with 0, after it returns that the key doesn't exist since the corresponding value is zero, shouldn't it go to the else statement? In that case, wouldn't it still be 1 search rather than 2?

Comment: @Potato `if (m[sName])` does one search, `... << m[sName]` does the second.